# DAX - RANK Function

Tags: mdx, dax

I have a RANK code from WEBI and need to write similar one in DAX or MDX.Both can work. But DAX will be more useful.

```
=Rank([OrderCount];([Category1];[Category2];[Category3]))
```

I have tried below code in DAX but it is not exact what i need.

```
=RANK.EQ(table1[OrderCount];table1[OrderCount])
```

Can you help me out write similar?

[Grouping by Count. This is extra.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkB9K.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very good at DAX, but MDX way is the following:

```
with
Dynamic Set OrderedSet as
Order(
    NonEmptyCrossJoin(
        [Dim Product].[Subcategory Name].[Subcategory Name].Members,
        [Dim Product].[Category Name].[Category Name].Members
        [Measures].[Order Quantity],
        2
    ),
    [Measures].[Order Quantity],
    BDESC
)

Member [Measures].[Rank] as
Rank(

        ([Dim Product].[Subcategory Name].Currentmember, 
        [Dim Product].[Category Name].Currentmember),
        OrderedSet
)

select 
{[Measures].[Order Quantity],[Measures].[Rank]} on 0,
non empty OrderedSet on 1
from 
[Adventure Works DW2016CTP3]
```

DenseRank:

```
with
Dynamic Set OrderedSet as
Order(
    NonEmptyCrossJoin(
      [Dim Product].[Subcategory Name].[Subcategory Name].Members,
      [Dim Product].[Category Name].[Category Name].Members,
      [Measures].[Order Quantity],
       2
    ),
    [Measures].[Order Quantity],
    BDESC
)

Dynamic Set DenseOrderedSet as
Order(
    NonEmpty(
       OrderedSet,
       [Measures].[RankFirstMatch]
    ),
    [Measures].[Order Quantity],
    BDESC
)

Member [Measures].[Rank] as
Rank(
  ([Dim Product].[Subcategory Name].Currentmember,[Dim Product].[Category Name].CurrentMember),
  OrderedSet
)

Member [Measures].[RankFirstMatch] as
IIF(
    [Measures].[Order Quantity] 
    =
    (
        OrderedSet.Item([Measures].[Rank] -2),
        [Measures].[Order Quantity]
    ),
    NULL,
    [Measures].[Rank]
)

Member [Measures].[RankDenseSet] as
Rank(
  ([Dim Product].[Subcategory Name].Currentmember,[Dim Product].[Category Name].CurrentMember),
  DenseOrderedSet
)


Member [Measures].[DenseRank] as
IIF(
    [Measures].[RankDenseSet] = 0,
    (OrderedSet.Item([Measures].[Rank] -2),[Measures].[DenseRank]),
    [Measures].[RankDenseSet]
)


select {[Measures].[Order Quantity],[Measures].[Rank],[Measures].[RankFirstMatch],[Measures].[RankDenseSet],[Measures].[DenseRank]} on 0,
non empty OrderedSet on 1
from [Adventure Works DW2016CTP3]
```

Comment: by this code; is it ordering by only Category dimension? And then can i add more dimensions after `[Order].[Category].[Category].Members` ?

Comment: Sure, you can add as many as you want. If you could be more describive about your cube structure and what you want to achive after all, I could write a code you need.

Comment: Let's build a code on Adventure Works db. I am also not sure about achive because, i just need to do what this WEBI code do:  `int RANK(measure[;ranking_dims][;top|bottom][;reset_dims])` . Need to create same with DAX or MDX. But i think, this formule tell something like; ranking [Order Quantity] ordering by product category and sub category

Comment: If you need to add an extra attribute to your report (say, [Order].[Status]), all you need is replace my script with the following code:

1. [Order].[Category].CurrentMember - > [Order].[Category].CurrentMember * [Order].[Status].CurrentMember

2. [Order].[Category].[Category].Members -> [Order].[Category].[Category].Members * [Order].[Status].[Status].Members

Comment: Below code returns some result. But need to test with client data to be sure it is correct or not. `WITH
MEMBER  [Measures].[RankOrderCount] as
RANK ( ( [Dim Product].[Subcategory Name].Currentmember, [Dim Product].[Category Name].Currentmember ) ,
ORDER  (( [Dim Product].[Subcategory Name].Members,[Dim Product].[Category Name].Members),  [Measures].[Order Quantity] ,BASC))
SELECT{ [Measures].[Order Quantity], [Measures].[RankOrderCount] } on 0, NON EMPTY ( [Dim Product].[Category Name].Members , [Dim Product].[Subcategory Name].Members ) on 1 FROM [Adventure Works DW2016CTP3]`

Comment: Also after adding [Product Name] dimension, query run long and couldn't wait for result. I cancelled query. Do you know how optimiza it?

Comment: This code didn't give actual result. I have created a result in below image. I copied it from real data just replaced values. http://tinypic.com/r/a3wbn/9. Can you please help to get same result with image?

Comment: I've rewritten my code with the nonempty to speed it up. Try it.

Comment: Your code is working fine. I have added a new screenshot in description. Can you please have a look it too? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The Rank function works as an iterator, every tuple has its unique number.

Comment: In addition, Is it possible to show only top 5 result or show only rows which have Rank grater than a specific number in same query? If not possible, i can use filter in tablix.

Comment: Sure, you want to use TopCount and Filter functions.

Comment: Yes, I need to select data by filters and RANK result then finally will show only rows which less than a specific value. ex RANK<=10. BTW, your code works fine on AdventureWorks db but when i use same on my real project i don't get any rows. It can be possible? Just it is working when i put Order in Rank like this: `Rank(  
        [Dim Product].[Category Name].Currentmember,
Order( 
        [Dim Product].[Category Name].[Category Name].Members,
        [Measures].[Order Quantity],
        BDESC)
)`

Comment: That means you're doing something wrong with porting your code. Rank doesn't return Nulls, at least it must return 0.

Comment: Ok. forgot about it. Is it fine to continue with previous comment(Top and Filters)?

Comment: I've added the DenseRank algorithm above. Speaking of TopCount and Filter: please close this question and ask new one. They are hardly related to the initial question.

Comment: I really appreciated much for all your answers and comments. That is exactly what i need. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the DAX measure for your question:

```css
Rank =
IF (
    HASONEVALUE ( YourTableName[ProductName] ),
    RANKX (
        ALL ( YourTableName ),
        CALCULATE ( SUM ( YourTableName[Order Quantity] ) ),
        ,
        ,
        DENSE
    )
)
```

IF (HASONEVALUE ( YourTableName[ProductName] )....  part will eliminate your Grand Total from showing 1